# How to upload files one by one to Google Drive using Google app script

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, google-apps-script

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on file input change event at my GoogleApp page. 
At global, I want to upload files one by one; and before sending to server, show file name with "sending" status, but "files" propery always is "undefined".

This is my code:

```
<form id="myForm"> 
    <input type="file" name="myFiles" id="myFiles" multiple="multiple"  >  
</form> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>   
    $(document).on('change', '#myFiles', function ()
    { 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
        { 
            console.log(this.files[i].name);  
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `IFRAME` sandbox mode.  Use `HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME`:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

`NATIVE`mode probably does not allow the `multiple="multiple"` attribute in input tags.  It's probably getting sanitized by caja.